# What is it about egg matzos that makes them forbidden to Ashkenazim?

Tags: halacha, passover, matzah

On boxes of Manischewitz Egg Matzos, you will find markings that say "Kosher for Passover" and also "According to Ashkenazic practice, all egg matzo may be eaten only by the young, infirm, or aged.  If you are of Sephardic ancestry, consult your rabbi."

I assume since these say "Kosher for Passover" that the water and time restrictions were observed.  I do not think they are chametz or kitniyot so what is it that makes them unacceptable?  To be clear, I am not looking for an excuse to use them for the seder, I just want to understand the reasoning behind the restriction.

In case it is useful, the ingredients list says:  Passover wheat flour, whole eggs, and apple cider.

Comment: Slightly related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27413 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/26909 and http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/447

Comment: Rambam explicitly allows it except on the first day of the holiday, due to the requirement to eat lechem oni, poor man's bread, at the seder.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Matzah made with other liquids besides (instead of) water are called "matzah ashira" enriched matzahs. While some object to them because they undercut the "lechem oni" bread of affliction that water/flour matzot represent, there are other concerns regarding whether they create an environment for fermentation.

[Here](http://www.crcweb.org/ask_rav/eggmatzah.php) is one treatment of the argument with the sides laid out and sources provided.

Comment: Does that prohibit the egg matzohs only for the seder, or for all of Passover? Is it prohibited to have egg matzohs in one's house during Passover?

Comment: the authorities which forbid it, forbid its consumption all during the holiday. Some allow it but not at he seder. You must consult your local halachic authority for anything more specific.

Comment: We consider they are not chametz with regards to owning them on Pesach, and if we do own them we can eat them after Pesach (unlike Chametz which remains forever forbidden) and that is also why we are lenient and allow them not to those who find it hard to eat regular matzo. We just avoid eating them due to the extra severity

Answer (score 5):

The sources provided above do not explain why Ashkenazim are מחמיר not to eat them at all during pesach (i.e. even not during the seder).  I think the answer to this question is: Making matza with fruit juices AND water leads to faster leavening (SA 462:2).  Hence, if any water was added, so then even if the matza was made within 18 minutes it might be חמץ.  Therefore, our of a concern that some water mized in, the Rema ruled not use it at all during Pesach, if not necessary (See Mishna Berura 462:15, where he also notes that there are שיטות that fruit juices speed up, not slow down, the leavening process)